# Cannot convert type Data to expected type Data

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm having a little problem when saving and loading a custom class to UserDefaults. The problem is the mentioned above, when I'm loading some encpnded Data from UserDefaults and trying to decode it using NSKeyedUnarchiver it tells me " Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Data' ". I tryed various things already but this error doesn't make sense.

```
tatic func saveGrupo(data: [Grupo]) {
    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: Grupo.key)
}

static func loadGrupo() -> [Grupo]? {
    let decoded  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Grupo.key) as! Data
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Grupo]
}
```

This is my saving and loading code.

And here is my class declaration, in case there is something wrong in here:

```
class Grupo: NSObject, NSCoding, Decodable {

//MARK: Properties

let id: Int
let name: String

static let key = "groups"

//MARK: Archiving Paths

static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Groups")

//MARK: Types

struct PropertyKey {
    static let id = "id"
    static let name = "name"
}

//MARK: Initializer

init(id: Int,name: String) {

    self.id = id
    self.name = name

}

//MARK: NSCoding

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(id, forKey: PropertyKey.id)
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String else {
        return nil
    }

    let id = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: PropertyKey.id)

    self.init(id: id,name: name)
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try using `data(forKey:)` instead of `object(forKey:)`?

Comment: And point out the exact line causing the error.